# Gitlab CI generates a new Facebook hash key for every build

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, continuous-integration, apk

I have a react-native app that should use Gitlab CI for debug and release builds. Currently I sign my android app using build.gradle signingConfigs.

The problem is that every time I trigger a build in CI a new facebook hash key is generated causing the app to crash in authentication since facebook does not expect a new value.

Our CI environment uses Docker shared runners so I believe that using a new machine to deploy the app causes a new Facebook hash key being generated.

Is there a way I can make my hash key constant for every build irregardless of the machine that is running the gradlew assembleRelease?

Answer (score 1):

Use a BuildConfig variable to store the hash key or store it as an environment variable in your gitlab ci configuration. Whenever/wherever you use the hash pull it from BuildConfig or your environment variable setting.

Comment: currently my config object looks like this:
you're saying I should have an attribute names hashkey or something?
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("KeyStore.jks")
            storePassword "xxxxxx"
            keyAlias "xxxxx"
            keyPassword "xxxxx"
        }
    }